# Search for multiple strings, msgbox when found, call other sub if not

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, msgbox

Had to extend my previous sub.
Need to find any of the three strings (errors, but stored as text).
If found, msgbox with warning and stop the sub.
If not found, call other sub.

Below is my code so far.
The thing is that I get the other sub called also when the strings are found.

```
Sub Z_ZWR_sprawdzbledy()
    Dim MyAr(1 To 3) As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("komunikat_OS_zwroty")

    MyAr(1) = "#VALUE!"
    MyAr(2) = "#N/A"
    MyAr(3) = "#REF!"
    
    With ws
        '~~> Loop through the array
        For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
            Set aCell = Worksheets("komunikat_OS_zwroty").Cells.Find(What:=MyAr(i), LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                Set bCell = aCell
                MsgBox "UWAGA! Znaleziono bledy!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "SPRAWDZ KOMORKI Z #N/A!, #N/D! lub #REF!"
             Else
            End If
          Next
          Call zwrot2

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: a) What about a simple `Exit Sub` after you found an error string? Otherwise you get the message box, but continue the loop. b) If you want to execute an `Exit For` alternatively (i.e. go outside the `For .. Next` block), you would have to assign a boolean value (e.g. `Dim ok as Boolean`, `okay = False` inside the block code, and add a condition outside (i.e. after `Next`) like `If okay Then zwrot2` to start zwrot2 only if there is *no*  error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution. The code loops through the given range, and if there is an error, the message will appear and the variable "blnCheckErrors" is set to true.

After the loop is finished the if-statement will check the "blnCheckErrors". If it's false, then the given procedure/sub will be executed.

```
Sub Z_ZWR_sprawdzbledy()
Dim MyAr(1 To 3) As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim blnCheckErrors as boolean

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("komunikat_OS_zwroty")

MyAr(1) = "#VALUE!"
MyAr(2) = "#N/A"
MyAr(3) = "#REF!"

With ws
    '~~> Loop through the array
    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
```

'I optimizied the code here a little bit, because you did use the same statement as above (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("komunikat_OS_zwroty"))

```
        Set aCell = .Cells.Find(What:=MyAr(i), LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell 'Edit: What is this for? It seems that you don't use it again
            MsgBox "UWAGA! Znaleziono bledy!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "SPRAWDZ KOMORKI Z #N/A!, #N/D! lub #REF!"
            blnCheckErrors = true
        End If

      Next
```

'the "Call"-statement isn't necessary anymore, just use the name of the sub/function

```
      if blnCheckErrors = false then zwrot2

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, zwrot2 gets called regardless.
You need to move Call zwrot2 into the For loop, and then (I guess) inside your IF statement after the ELSE.

Comment: Doesn't work this way, then it gets executed three times, but should just once.

Comment: Good point - as an alternative to an exit sub, you could also add a counter.
Set it to 0 at first, then increment it if you find one of the strings you look for.

After the loop, you add an IF counter > 0 Then call zwrot2
; and also display that messagebox once by calling it from that IF statement on counter >0